# swipeUp or swipeDown is not valid in google chrome which emulates mobile platform

Tags: jquery, html, css, touch, zepto

as the title description,i write html codes which applies on mobile platform,then i test codes through  google chrome which can emulate mobile phone to access the web pages.the codes as follows.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        html,
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        body{
            background: palegreen;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <script src="js/zepto.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/touch.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $("body").swipeUp(function() {
            alert("hello swipeUp");
        })
        $("body").swipeDown(function() {
            alert("hello swipeDown");
        })
        $("body").tap(function() {
            alert("hello tap");
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

at last,i find "swipeUp" or "swipeDown" is not valid in google chrome and “tap” will be triggered twice.please help me,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not hesitate to write how you tested the problem, because you told that it did not work in Google Chrome, but you not wrote in which browsers it didn´t work. The better you describe your problem, the better answer you can obtain. Could you please describe more informations about your problem?

Are you assured that "js/zepto.min.js" is available?

(maybe it is not best idea, but about this you can play more with JS and scroll events)

Comment: thank you for your answer.aepto.min.js is similar to jquery.min.js.i use chrome(pc) open this html and toggle device toolbar as mobile.i only test google chrome and want to know why it donot work.

Comment: I tried to use the same thing on my server and test in mobile, but didn't work.. sorry... when I find real answer, then I will post it for you here...

Comment: I was trying to find why it behaves so, but only thing that I found is that zepto.js and touch.js should have in disposition hammer.js but with specific version... too high version of hammer.js tend to make a problem... another advice I have for you is to update your question with logs from debugging... for example firebug in mozilla, but you were talking about chrome, then you can use developer tools: "Ctrl+Shift+I" in browser page... and try to find out if some errors not occure or try to debug your code during tapping... you can choose mobile devices emulator in chrome to do it...